# made a bot in a telegram with a database for spam in private messages, does not work

Tags: python, database, telegram

**this is the main code**
I think this code is correct but I'm not sure.
the problem is that I want to make a bot with mailing to users whose ids are recorded in the database, but it does not work

```
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
import logging
import sqlite3
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher,executor,types
from aiogram.types.message import ContentTypes
from aiogram.types.message import ContentType
import markups as nav
import aiogram.utils.markdown as fmt
from db import Database



TOKEN = '--'



logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
db = Database('database.db')


storage = MemoryStorage()


###here the bot sends a message to the person cook only accepts his request in a closed channel
@dp.chat_join_request_handler()
async def start1(update: types.ChatJoinRequest):

    await update.approve()

    await bot.send_message(chat_id=update.from_user.id, text=f"{fmt.hide_link('https://huntflow.ru/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/9.png')}"
                           'Это официальный телеграм бот который рекомендует инетесный тебе контент\n'
                                                             '\n'
                                                             'Подписывайся на эти каналы'
                                                             '\n'
                                                             '\n'
                                                             '▲Pussy Tight▲ - https://t.me/+Pdfh8tg4CRNiMmJh\n'
                                                             '\n'
                                                             '▲Pussy Tight Hentai▲ - https://t.me/+UHyaBhvEj8Y5ZDQx', reply_markup=nav.MainMenu
                           )


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
            db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=f"{fmt.hide_link('https://huntflow.ru/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/9.png')}"
                           'Это официальный телеграм бот который рекомендует инетесный тебе контент\n'
                                                             '\n'
                                                             'Подписывайся на эти каналы'
                                                             '\n'
                                                             '\n'
                                                             '▲Pussy Tight▲ - https://t.me/+Pdfh8tg4CRNiMmJh\n'
                                                             '\n'
                                                             '▲Pussy Tight Hentai▲ - https://t.me/+UHyaBhvEj8Y5ZDQx', reply_markup=nav.MainMenu
                           )
###this function is responsible for the fact that when the admin can send a message to all people who are in the database

@dp.message_handler(commands=['sendall'])
async def sendall(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.from_user.id == id_admin:
         text = message.text[9:]
         users = db.get_users()
         for row in users:
             try:
                await bot.send_message(row[0], text)
                if int(row[1]) != 1:
                    db.set_active(row[0], 1)
             except:
                 db.set_active(row[0], 0)

         await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Успешная рассылка')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

**this is the database code**
wrote after INSERT - OR REPLACE the code is simply skipped and nothing can be sent

```
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,)).fetchmany(1)
            return bool(len(result))

    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_id') VALUES (?)", (user_id,))

    def set_active(self, user_id, active):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE 'users' SET 'active' = ? WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (active, user_id,))

    def get_users(self):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("SELECT 'user_id', 'active' FROM 'users'").fetchall()
```

**error:**
I was told that there may be a problem with the brackets, but it does not help

```
File "D:\spambot\venv\db.py", line 15, in add_user
    return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_id') VALUES (?)", (user_id,))
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.user_id
```

Comment: What's the point of `with self.connection:`?

Comment: The error is saying you are trying to add a user that already exists.  Your text mentions "INSERT OR REPLACE", but that's not what you have here.